# Love2d can't find font file in the same directory

Tags: fonts, lua, love2d

I'm using love2d 0.10.1. Love2d returns error that font file cannot be loaded as it doesn't exist. However the file is in a child directory. I tried giving full path with filename and it won't work. The font file **has to be** in another directory because in will not be included in the final exe.

My current directories look like this

```
--- love 2d
------ game
---------- main.lua
---------- fonts
-------------- segoeui.ttf
------ love.exe
```

And will look like this when the final exe is made

```
--- love 2d
------ fonts
---------- segoeui.ttf
------ game.exe
```

My code (simplified)

```
love.window.setMode(500, 500)  -- Open window
font = love.graphics.newFont('segoeui.ttf', 20)  -- Load font
love.graphics.print(text, 100, 100)  -- Print text
love.graphics.present()  -- Display text
while true do end
```

Error message

[image]

I found someone saying this is because love can't access folders outside main one so I tried this

```
love.window.setMode(500, 500)  -- Open window
local file = io.open("fonts\\segoeui.ttf", "r")
local content = file:read "*a"
local data, err = love.filesystem.newFileData(content, 'segoeui.ttf')
font = love.graphics.newFont(data, 20)  -- Load font
love.graphics.print("hey", 100, 100)  -- Print text
love.graphics.present()  -- Display text
while true do end
```

This way io.open opens the file successfully, content is read then converted into a FileData and then fed to newFont. However this returns the error that font can't be loaded because data is incorrect. I guess it's not the way to load it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken, you want the font to be in the directory of the application that you're running with love2d (the .lua files), not in the directory with the love2d executable.

Comment: Oh right it works now. But isn't there a way to use them directly from the windows font directory (C:\Windows\Fonts). If not, I have to copy maybe 20Mo of fonts that's quite a lot.

Comment: Also this seems to be the same with every love2d functions: you can't use file outside the working directory

Comment: The simple test would be to put a file "filename.png" one directory above your present working directory and see if "../filename.png" can be accessed. If so, then you know that you can access files outside of the present working directory.

Comment: I changed my question to fit more my needs. Basically how do I load something in another directory?

Comment: Hmm, that's weird. From an architecture perspective do you really want your application to be dependent on C:\Windows\Fonts anyway? It may be better to keep all resources that your application is dependent on "fonts, images, etc" in directories under the applications root to allow you to easily distribute it. Can you see a font if you put one in the relative path "fonts/font.ttf"?

Comment: Nope I can't see it that's the problem (says doesn't exist). And I copied the fonts I needed into fonts directory instead of using windows font directory.

Comment: Turns out I needed to use / instead of \\. I can access folder inside game folder but still cannot access folder in the same directory as the game folder...

Comment: Then you possibly can only access directories within the root of the application. This could be done to avoid having dependencies outside of the project.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120809/discussion-between-atom-and-cricket).